# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr with angualrJs when i use routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

this is part of my problem = https://jsfiddle.net/2vrz38d6/
it contain just the js part open the console to see what i have

i get confused to solve this error
Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.10/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%…3A9641%2Fassets%2Fglobal%2Fplugins%2Fangularjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A435)
```

---

My Error happen with routing in angularJs 
the error which i took it is : 
[my Error page here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:unpr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.10%2F$injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524routeProvider%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9641%2Fassets%2Fglobal%2Fplugins%2Fangularjs%2Fangular.min.js:6:417%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9641%2Fassets%2Fglobal%2Fplugins%2Fangularjs%2Fangular.min.js:38:307%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9641%2Fassets%2Fglobal%2Fplugins%2Fangularjs%2Fangular.min.js:36:308)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.e%20%5Bas%20invoke%5D%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9641%2Fassets%2Fglobal%2Fplugins%2Fangularjs%2Fangular.min.js:37:64)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9641%2Fassets%2Fglobal%2Fplugins%2Fangularjs%2Fangular.min.js:35:301)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9641%2Fassets%2Fglobal%2Fplugins%2Fangularjs%2Fangular.min.js:35:425%0A%20%20%20%20at%20s%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9641%2Fassets%2Fglobal%2Fplugins%2Fangularjs%2Fangular.min.js:7:302)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9641%2Fassets%2Fglobal%2Fplugins%2Fangularjs%2Fangular.min.js:35:202)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Ob%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9641%2Fassets%2Fglobal%2Fplugins%2Fangularjs%2Fangular.min.js:38:435)

my code is :

```
(function () {
    var MyApp = angular.module('myApp');


    MyApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/expenses.html',
                controller: 'CurriculumController'
            })



       .otherwise({
           redirectTo: '/'

       });
```

and the controller

```
        MyApp.controller('CurriculumController', ['$scope', '$rest', function ($scope, $rest) { 
//some stuf here
```

for my script angular file :
in the first i have this

```
 <script src="/assets/global/plugins/angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
```

and in the middle of the project i have 
the file of my angular apps

```
<script src="/Scripts/NGModel/Curriculum/Curriculum.js"></script>
```

and after that the file of the routing part for angularjs

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are wrapping everything in self executing anonymous function ...Hope you are calling it along with the other suggestions mentioned below in answers  like this (function(){})()

Comment: the code is running on WAMP server at my side. but on the fiddle it isn't.

Comment: try restarting the browser, clearing cache and cookies and launch it with `angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);`. Don't include `min.js` include the **not** minified js files, so that the errors are printed properly on console.

Answer (score 1):

you have to include `angular-route.js`.

Dependency injection would be `angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);`

**EDIT as the inclusion of Angular libraries were updated in the OP's problem statement :-**

**Replace**

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>` **with**

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.10/angular-route.min.js"></script>` as you have mentioned in comments that you are using v1.3.10

And as @Garrett has suggested, add,

`.otherwise("/");`

Comment: i have the same error and no thing changed i tried with it before

Comment: which Angular version?

Comment: Can you please edit the question and show where/how are you adding Angular files.?

Comment: check if it works now. your version of Angular and Angular Router weren't matching either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82859/discussion-between-user44444-and-sudhansu-choudhary).

Answer (score 1):

As people above have suggested, you need to include that file, but you also need to make sure that you are doing it in the correct order as well in your index file. I suppose trying a different set of CDNs wouldn't hurt either.

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Also, in your route configurations, just a mention that you can do this as well for your otherwise:

```
MyApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/expenses.html',
        controller: 'CurriculumController'
    })
    .otherwise("/");
});
```

Comment: i tried a lot but no thing changed i did like what you said but the same problem again when i delete config part the project work when i use it the project get down again

Comment: And you have included the routes config in your app definition? 

`var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);`

Comment: can you check this https://jsfiddle.net/2vrz38d6/
this is part of my code open the console to see the problem

Comment: Alright man, I made a Plunkr because I like it a little better than JSFiddle so I hope you dont mind. Here is a working example of how to use the ngRoute module and a good way to organize your angular code. Let me know if you have any questions. plnkr.co/edit/Bl0J6Z4WSDf637ApYNrl

Comment: @user44444 Did you end up figuring this out?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make this work:

1) Add the angular-route file:
  Include the file below the angular.js

```
 <script src="angular-route.js">
```

2) Inject the ng-route at the definition of your app:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ng-route']);
```

Comment: this is what i have and i get the same problem 

<script src="~/Scripts/NGModel/Curriculum/Curriculum.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>

 <div class="row" ng-controller="CurriculumController" ng-init="init();">

Comment: can you check this https://jsfiddle.net/2vrz38d6/
this is part of my code open the console to see the problem

Comment: Alright man, I made a Plunkr because I like it a little better than JSFiddle so I hope you dont mind. Here is a working example of how to use the ngRoute module and a good way to organize your angular code. Let me know if you have any questions. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/Bl0J6Z4WSDf637ApYNrl

Answer (score 0):

you should add your dependencies in to the module like this

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Comment: yes but it's not working you can check my example to see its not work https://jsfiddle.net/2vrz38d6/

Comment: No dash(-) between ng and Route it should be ngRoute not ng-Route

Comment: mmmm i will try but i dont think so

Comment: it's not working you can make an example on https://jsfiddle.net/2vrz38d6/
and show me